# Nakayama’s Lemma for local rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I have to prove this form of Nakayama’s lemma:

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a local ring $R$ with maximal ideal $I$. If there is $m_1,…,m_K \in M$ such that $\bar{m_1},…,\bar{m_k}$ generate $M/IM$ as an $R/I$ vector space, then $m_1,…,m_k$ generate $M$ as an $R$ module.

I know the version:

Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module and $I$ an ideal of $R$ with $IM=M$. Then there is an element $a \in I$ with $am=m$ for all $m \in M$.

And with this version I proved another version for local rings

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a local ring $R$. If there is a proper ideal $I$ of $R$ with $IM=M$ then $M=0$.

So I have that
$$M/IM= <\bar{m_1},…,\bar{m_k}>_{R/I}$$
then
$$M=IM +N$$
when $N=\sum_{i}^{k}Rm_i$. Now we can consider the quotient
$$M/N=(IM+N)/N=(IM)/N=I\cdot (M/N)$$
and for the second form that I wrote, we have
$$M=N.$$
My question is about
$$M/IM= <\bar{m_1},…,\bar{m_k}>_{R/I} \implies M=IM +N$$
why is it licit?
I tried with a direct computation: if I take $m+IM \in M/IM$ We have
$$m+IM=(r_1+I)(m_1+IM) +…+(r_k+I)(m_k+IM)$$
with $r_1,…,r_k \in R$.
But I don’t know how to work with the right part of this equality.
Is it lecit to write:

$$m+IM=(r_1+I)(m_1+IM) +…+(r_k+I)(m_k+IM)=\\=(r_1m_1+…+r_km_k +IM)+I(m_1+…+m_k)=\\=(r_1m_1+…+r_km_k)+IM?$$

How can I prove the implication? And how can I work with this type of sum (quotient of modules + quotient of rings)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think working directly with ideal arithmetic makes things more confusing (it's not wrong, though).

It's simpler to reason this way: take an element $m\in M$. Then its residue in $M/IM$ can be written as
$$\overline{m} = \sum_i \overline{r_i}\overline{m_i}$$
which means that $m = \sum_i r_im_i + a$ with $a\in IM$, so $m\in IM+N$.